# Disable translation for rigid body?

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I have a rigid body with translations and rotations. I want to disable any translations completely. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by eromod, you can **lock the transformations** in the (n) properties shelf.

Another (Less good) idea: You can set the **Translation Damping** under **Rigid Body Dynamics** to 1, but this still allows the object move a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

make it a type: passive rigid body, instead of type: active.
[image]

Comment: Doesn't this also disable rotation on the rigid body?

Comment: oh maybe adding a rigid body constraint will help then? Like hinge maybe?

Comment: looks like locking the transformations in the (n) properties shelf works too